# elasticsearch querying only the document I want and saving it as a snapshot

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to find a way to back up (snapshot) and restore only the document(data) that I want out of Elastic Search.

I looked up the reference page of Elastic Search, but there was only a way to backup the entire index, but I couldn't find a backup by querying the desired document(data).
Is there a way to back up only the desired data using mysql?

The code below backs up the entire index by storing a basic snapshot.
How can I modify something here?

PUT /_snapshot/my_backup
{
  "type": "fs",
  "settings": {
    "location": "my_backup_location"
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating another index using your query, and then snapshot this new index.
You can use the [reindex api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) to create this new index